# what is the difference between model_arima_fit.plot_predict and model_arima_fit.forecast?

Tags: python, machine-learning, arima

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8VKu.png)

```
model_arima=ARIMA(X,order=(7,2,1))
model_arima_fit=model_arima.fit()
model_arima_fit.plot_predict(4,350)
predictions=model_arima_fit.forecast(steps=350)[0]
```

Is .plot_predict and .forecast is same? if yes,how can i get same values same values for both of them

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMAResults.plot_predict.html) `plot_predict` returns a matplotlib Figure object.

`forecast` returns the actual values in a numpy array